# Как записать в один массив разные значения по одинаковому id (PHP)?

Tags: php, массивы

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как превратить 1 в 2?

1.

```
/nArray
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => Тюриков Т.
            [city] => Нижний Новгород
            [car] => Audi R8
            [result] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => Тюриков Т.
            [city] => Нижний Новгород
            [car] => Audi R8
            [result] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => Тюриков Т.
            [city] => Нижний Новгород
            [car] => Audi R8
            [result] => 0
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => Тюриков Т.
            [city] => Нижний Новгород
            [car] => Audi R8
            [result] => 48
        )
```

2. 

```
array(
            'id'=>1,
            'name'=>'Тюриков Т.',
            'city'=>'Нижний Новгород',
            'car'=>'Audi R8',
            '1'=>0,
            '2'=>0,
            '3'=>0,
            '4'=>48
)
```

Comment: циклом пробегитесь по исходному массиву и соберите новый массив свой мечты

Answer (score 0):

как-нибудь так мб

```
$results = array_column($arr, 'result');
$first   = $arr[0];
unset($first, 'result');
$result  = array_merge($first, $resuls)  ;
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]